# Nginx real_ip_header through a GCE ingress?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, kubernetes-ingress

My goal is to filter access by IP address of an angular app deployed on Kubernetes Engine served by nginx through a GCE ingress.

But on my nginx the remote_addr is not right.

**$LB_IP is the ip defined here :     kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: app-angular**

I'm using set_real_ip_from on nginx to set the ip from X-Forwarded-For

```
set_real_ip_from $LB_IP;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

The original ip comes in the X-Forwarded-For header as expected from the google doc : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#components

I can see the X-Forwarded-For contains the $CLIENT_IP but the remote_addr is not correct, and by the way my filter on IP is not working. Any idea ?

My nginx logs :

> 10.40.40.40 - - [07/Feb/2018:11:29:48 +0000] "GET /styles.bundle.css HTTP/1.1" 200 35908 "http://MY_URL/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36" "$CLIENT_IP, $LB_IP"

But i want :

> $CLIENT_IP - - [07/Feb/2018:11:29:48 +0000] "GET /styles.bundle.css HTTP/1.1" 200 35908 "http://MY_URL/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36" "$CLIENT_IP, $LB_IP"

**My Ingress configuration :**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: app-angular
spec:
  rules:
    - host: MY_URL
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: app-backend
            servicePort: 80
```

**My backend configuration :**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-backend
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: app-angular
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

**My deployment configuration :**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-angular
spec:
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-angular
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-angular
        image: gcr.io/MY_PROJECT/app-angular:MY_TAG
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

**My nginx configuration :**

```
server {
  listen 80;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {

    set_real_ip_from $LB_IP;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

    allow 130.211.0.0/22; #Google IP
    allow $CLIENT_IP; # FILTERED IP
    allow 10.0.0.0/8; #internal network
    deny all;

    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

They are two solutions (Thks to gcbirzan for helping me on GCP slack):

**1) Update My nginx configuration with the good IPS from IP addresses ranges    :**

IP addresses ranges can be found here : https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/networks/list. 
You can just add set_real_ip_from for a region or all needed regions. 
Don't forget real_ip_recursive on;

```
server {
  listen 80;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {

    set_real_ip_from 10.128.0.0/20;
    ...
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;

    allow 130.211.0.0/22; #Google IP
    allow $CLIENT_IP; # FILTERED IP
    allow 10.0.0.0/8; #internal network
    deny all;

    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

}
```

**2) Update My backend configuration with :**

externalTrafficPolicy: Local

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-backend
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: app-angular
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

Update nginx configuration :

now the IP shown in $remote_addr will be set with the Load balancer IP for your client requests and with google Infra IPS : 130.211.0.0/22,35.191.0.0/16

Don't forget real_ip_recursive on;

```
server {
  listen 80;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {

    set_real_ip_from $LB_IP;
    set_real_ip_from 130.211.0.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 35.191.0.0/16;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;

    allow 130.211.0.0/22; #Google IP
    allow 35.191.0.0/16; #Google IP
    allow $CLIENT_IP; # FILTERED IP
    allow 10.0.0.0/8; #internal network
    deny all;

    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is for GCP load balancers specifically. 
As for the nginx Load Balancer, you should consider adding the [ExternalTrafficPolicy annotation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-typenodeport) to your NodePort service to preserve the client IP.

I also found a similar issue dating back to mid-2017 which shows there was an issue with [certain versions of the nginx controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/800), make sure that the image you are using does not still have this issue.

Finally, you may need to add [use-proxy-protocol: "true" with the configuration ConfigMap](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1067) since you are using an ingress which acts as an HTTP(S) Load Balancer which uses proxies.

Comment: Thks for you help, i found a solution. The ExternalTrafficPolicy was a good way.  

The last point is not possible : use-proxy-protocol: "true" , Because i'm not using nginx-ingress, i'm using gce ingress with nginx as http server for my angular app.

Answer (score 0):

We're using a `HTTP GCLB ingress` in front of `nginx ingress`.  To get the `RealIP` to work I added

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    k8s-addon: ingress-nginx.addons.k8s.io
data:
  ##
  ## Google Infra Blocks needed
  ##  130.211.0.0/22,35.191.0.0/16
  ##
  ## Google Cloud Load Balancer
  ##  GCLB-IP/32
  proxy-real-ip-cidr: 130.211.0.0/22,35.191.0.0/16,[YOUR-GCLB-IP]/32
```

This allows the `nginx` to trust the `X-Forwarded-For` from Google's infrastructure.

Comment: Thks for you help, i found a solution. But i'm not using nginx-ingress, i'm using gce ingress with nginx as http server for my angular app.

Comment: Ahh. Thx for the clarification.  I conflated the mention of `nginx with GCE ingress` as `GCLB Ingress in front of nginx Ingress`.